# Bash command to create a folder and move specific files into it

Tags: bash, mv, mkdir, move

I am trying to achieve this using bash

I have a directory of files, a sample to get the picture is below:

```
January 2010 MA - C3 Edexcel.pdf
January 2010 MS - C3 Edexcel.pdf    
January 2010 QP - C3 Edexcel.pdf    
January 2011 MA - C3 Edexcel.pdf 
January 2011 MS - C3 Edexcel.pdf    
January 2011 QP - C3 Edexcel.pdf
```

I am looking for a command that will take the three files from each year and put it into a folder for that year, for example, the first three files should go into a folder called 2010 and the second group of three files should go into a folder called 2011.

So what I am trying to do is

```
 mkdir 2010| mv *2010* 2010
```

For every year in the file

To be clear, the folder is much larger than what I showed, meaning doing it year by year would take too much time

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snipet of an script will do what you ask for several years:

```
for i in $(seq 2010 2020); do 
    mkdir -p "$i" && 
    mv *"$i"*.pdf "$i"
done
```

Comment: You should really put `$i` into quotes (`"$i"`). Once you do that, you can discard the curly braces, so `mv *"$i"*.pdf "$i"`. And you don’t need the curly braces in `mkdir "$i"`, either. You don’t need the `;` at the end of the line, and I do things like this just fine without putting the `/` at the end of the directory name.  And consider using `mkdir -p`, so the command doesn’t fail if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to understand it

```
mkdir 2010 && mv *2010*pdf !$
```

& same thing for 2011 ...

here a solution to loop on many years files

```
for i in $(seq 0 9) ; do mkdir 201${i} && mv *201${i}*pdf !$ ; done
```

Comment: The directory is much larger than what I showed, meaning it would take too long to do this

Comment: whatever the method you will use it will take time  :) but if you have too many 'years' to manage, you can script it in a loop (I edit answer to show how to)

Comment: Please use $(…) instead of backticks.

Comment: What are you expecting the `!$` to match?

Comment: !$ matches the last command parameter (only parameter) so directory name here

Comment: There is no directory name in your examples for it to match.

Comment: mkdir 201${i} here means mkdir 2010 at first iteration & 2011 at second and so on ... so yes this just works  ```  -bash-4.4$ mkdir toto && cd !$ ; pwd
mkdir toto && cd toto ; pwd
/home/francois/toto
-bash-4.4$
this just works absolutly fine :) as usual I did it on my station befor posting ... :) do not say this don't work until you did it for real